# Can I add subdomain that redirect to x.x.x.x/subfolder?

Tags: redirect, subdomain

I have the main domain site, but the client wants a subdomain that points to x.x.x.x/subfolder, when x.x.x.x is an external IP.

Its posible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `example.com` as the main domain and `foo.example.com` as the subdomain. You would have DNS A records for each of them, both pointing to the same x.x.x.x IP address. Then, in the web server software (I'll use IIS terms, but other web servers are similar) on the server that has that x.x.x.x IP address, you would set up two sites.

1. MainSite; listens on x.x.x.x, but only for the hostname of example.com; serves up content from C:\Website.
2. FooSite; also listens on x.x.x.x, but only for the hostname of foo.example.com; serves up content from C:\Website\Foo.